# JS date - I want to have a date in this format - 2022-08-14

Tags: javascript

I want to have a date in this format - 2022-08-14. Is this a good function for it?

```
   function myDate(){
    const d = new Date()
    let dy;
    let mon;
    
    if(d.getDate().toString().length === 1){
        dy = 0+d.getDate().toString()
    }else{
        dy = d.getDate().toString()
    }

    if(String(d.getMonth()+1).length === 1){
        mon = 0+String(d.getMonth()+1)
    }else{
        mon = String(d.getMonth()+1)
    }
    // year, month, date
    let realDate = `${d.getFullYear()}-${mon}-${dy}`
    return realDate
};
```

Comment: Try logging the accumulator and you will see why on second iteration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use the spread operator with each function to find the corresponding value, for example:

```
const arr = [-10, 1, 2, 17000, 1, 2, 200]

const x = {
  'max': Math.max(...arr),
  'min': Math.min(...arr)
}

console.log(x)
>>> { max: 17000, min: -10 }
```

Comment: I'm new to JS i prefer this solution a lot cleaner! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need a *`startValue`* for [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) which looks like the accumulator with large value for `Min` andlarge negative value for `max`.

If no *`startValue`* is given `reduce` takes the first value as accumulator value and the second item as value. Because of no expected object, all values are `NaN`.

```js
const
    array = [-10, 1, 2, 17000, 1, 2, 200],
    result = array.reduce(({ min, max }, value) => ({
        max: Math.max(max, value),
        min: Math.min(min, value)
    }), { min: Number.MAX_VALUE, max: -Number.MAX_VALUE });

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not try this instead:

```
const arr = [-10, 1, 2, 17000, 1, 2, 200]

let sortedArr = arr.sort((a, b) => a - b)

const x = {
 'max': sortedArr[sortedArr.length - 1],
 'min': sortedArr[0]
}


console.log(x)
```

Comment: Complexity- `O(n log n)`

Answer (score 0):

Using [`Function.prototype.apply()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)

```js
const array = [-10, 1, 2, 17000, 1, 2, 200],
  solution = {
    max: Math.max.apply(null, array),
    min: Math.min.apply(null, array),
  };

console.log(solution);
```